# wsgi sub-process PyMongo Bottle

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, bottle

I have a really simple BottlePy application that has a route that starts a new process using subprocess.Popen. Everything works great using the command:

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server app.wsgi
```

Put, when trying the apache configuration, I'm getting a strange exception, that maybe is related to pyMongo.

```
 File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import fields
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 6, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

My configuration is:

**httpd.conf:**

```
WSGIPythonPath "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

**httpd.vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName relferreira.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess relferreira user=relferreira group=staff processes=1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias "/" "/Users/relferreira/Documents/app.wsgi"
    WSGIProcessGroup relferreira
    <Directory "/Users/relferreira/Documents/">
        WSGIProcessGroup relferreira
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /Users/relferreira/Documents/api/error-bottle.log
    CustomLog /Users/relferreira/Documents/api/access-bottle.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**route (simplified):**
As you can see, I needed to pass the path to the sub-process, in order to it be able to load the modules

```
@route('/extract')
def extract():
    try:

        script_path = .....
        command = .....
        env = os.environ.copy()
        env['PYTHONPATH'] = ":".join(sys.path) 

        proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', script_path] + command, env=env)
    except SystemExit as e:
        abort(400, 'Wrong parameters')

    return 'success'
```

**otool -L:**

```
command: otool -L /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so
```

return:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so:
    /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

I installed Python using `Homebrew`. I know that I should be using virtualenv, put is a legacy project so, I'm trying to make it work without it.

Comment: On the ``mod_wsgi.so`` file you are loading into Apache run ``otool -L`` and add the output above. I would suspect that it is finding the wrong Python framework library. This can sometimes happens when using a non Apple, non PSF Python binary for Python as they sometimes aren't set up correctly so they can be used in an embedded manner. Where did you get this Python installation from?

Comment: I edited the question with the answers. Thanks in advance

Comment: Search '__PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder flat namespace' on Google and appears to pop up in various situations. Maybe dig through what Google gives you as I am not sure at this point. One suggest fix I do see is simply to uninstall HomeBrew Python and reinstall it. That helped one person at least.